# 2D Array of objects with virtual child methods -> "vtable referenced from" error

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, runtime-error, virtual

In my header for the Tile class, I defined a pure virtual method with no definition in the implementation: `virtual void setVals(int ID) = 0;`

The two classes which inherit Tile (Terrain and Actor) both overwrite the setVals method with the implementations:

```
void Terrain::setVals(int ID){
    switch(ID){
        case 1 : GFX_ = '.'; name_ = "Grass"; desc_ = "Some grass"; break;
        default: GFX_ = '?'; name_ = "Error"; desc_ = "Error"; Tile::isPassable_ = false; break;
    }
}
```

and

```
void Tile::setVals(int ID){
    switch(ID){
        case 1 : GFX_ = '?'; name_ = "Nothing"; desc_ = "You shouldn't be seeing this"; break;
        case 0 : GFX_ = '@'; name_ = "Player"; desc_ = "The Player"; break;
        default: GFX_ = '?'; name_ = "Error"; desc_ = "Error"; Tile::isPassable_ = false; break;
    }
}
```

respectively. An 2D array of each of these child classes is initialized in the Map class:

```
Terrain terrain_[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
Actor actors_[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
```

(where HEIGHT and WIDTH are constant ints). But when the program runs, the program returns a runtime error reading "'vtable for Actor', referenced from:". Am I making a mistake in how I'm initializing these methods or objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that your base class is `Tile`, and has the following pure virtual method

```
virtual void setVals(int ID) = 0;
```

But yet you went on to define it?

```
void Tile::setVals(int ID){
    switch(ID){
        case 1 : GFX_ = '?'; name_ = "Nothing"; desc_ = "You shouldn't be seeing this"; break;
        case 0 : GFX_ = '@'; name_ = "Player"; desc_ = "The Player"; break;
        default: GFX_ = '?'; name_ = "Error"; desc_ = "Error"; Tile::isPassable_ = false; break;
    }
}
```

You need to implement `Actor::setVals` if that is a derived class from `Tile`

Comment: I'm so sorry. My issue was that I had writen void Tile::setVals(int ID){... instead of void Actor::setVals(int ID){... in the Actor implementation file. Thank you so much, and I apologize for my stupidity.

Comment: @user1207515 No worries, we all make mistakes, especially on Fridays :)